# How to remove null rows from sql query result?

Tags: sql-server-2008, null

I have a SQL query in which I am getting some records.
Query is:

```
    select c.Id, c.FirstName, dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, '27,31') as Staff from Client c order by c.Id
```

Result is:
[image]

I want only those rows that are not having null values in column Staff.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You have to repeat the UDF, viz... where dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, '27,31') IS NOT NULL

Comment: write a conditional statement like if(!(Staff.Equals(NULL))){Query}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
select 
  c.Id, c.FirstName, dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, '27,31') as Staff 
from 
  Client c 
where
  dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, '27,31') is not null
order 
  by c.Id
```