# how to omit null values using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to only display the rows in which there is date for Researchers.
I cannot manage to omit the rows with Null Values. I even tried this solution [How to remove null rows from sql query result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211695/how-to-remove-null-rows-from-sql-query-result)..

This is my Query:

```
SELECT Submission.Title AS [Submission_Title], CA.Surname AS [Researchers], Submission.Status AS [Status] 
FROM Submission 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + r.Surname 
FROM ResearcherSubmission rs INNER JOIN Researcher r 
ON r.ResearcherID = rs.ResearcherID 
WHERE CONCAT (DATENAME(MONTH,[Submission].[SubmissionDate]), ' ',DATEPART (YEAR,[Submission].[SubmissionDate])) = 'October 2015'  
AND Submission.SubmissionID = rs.SubmissionID 
FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ')) AS CA (Surname) 
GROUP BY convert(varchar(10),datename(month,Submission.SubmissionDate)), Submission.Title, CA.Surname, Submission.Status;
```

This is my Current output:

[image]

any suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickfix, without reading query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT Submission.Title AS [Submission_Title], CA.Surname AS [Researchers], Submission.Status AS [Status] 
FROM Submission 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + r.Surname 
FROM ResearcherSubmission rs INNER JOIN Researcher r 
ON r.ResearcherID = rs.ResearcherID 
WHERE CONCAT (DATENAME(MONTH,[Submission].[SubmissionDate]), ' ',DATEPART (YEAR,[Submission].[SubmissionDate])) = 'October 2015'  
AND Submission.SubmissionID = rs.SubmissionID 
FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ')) AS CA (Surname) 
GROUP BY convert(varchar(10),datename(month,Submission.SubmissionDate)), Submission.Title, CA.Surname, Submission.Status
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Researchers IS NOT NULL;
```

There is probably more elegant solution, but you need to share sample data and structures.

This part may cause problems:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + r.Surname
```

try with `CONCAT` instead or :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ISNULL(r.Surname, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should filter out the researchers *before* the `group by` rather than afterwards.  When possible, it is better (performance-wise) to put conditions before aggregation.

```
SELECT s.Title AS Submission_Title, CA.Surname AS Researchers, s.Status 
FROM Submission s CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + r.Surname 
                    FROM ResearcherSubmission rs INNER JOIN
                         Researcher r 
                         ON r.ResearcherID = rs.ResearcherID 
                    WHERE s.SubmissionID = rs.SubmissionID 
                    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                   ), 1, 2, ' '))
    ) AS CA(Surname) 
WHERE s.SubmissionDate >= '2015-10-01' AND s.SubmissionDate < '2015-11-01' AND
      ca.Surname IS NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(s.SubmissionDate), MONTH(s.SubmissionDate), s.Title, CA.Surname, s.Status;
```

Note the changes made:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- I changed the date comparison to have no functions on the date itself.  This would allow SQL Server to use an index, if appropriate.
- I also moved the date comparison from the `CROSS APPLY` subquery to the outer query.  This could be a big gain in efficiency.  Why do the extra work for rows that will be filtered out anyway?
- I added the `NOT NULL` condition to the `WHERE` clause.
- The date key in the outer `GROUP BY` is redundant because the query is only using one month of data.  I simplified the logic but left it.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I see how this solution could be better performance-wise. However there a few issues that I have encountered and I cant figure out why. Firstly I have left my date as 'October 2015' on purpose as I am using a datetime picker to drill-down a report and display results monthly. So I will later replace 'October 2015'  with @0. I also get an error when I run the query saying 'STUFF' is not a recognized function name. I also think there is an extra bracket at the line , 1, 2, ' ')). I could be wrong. I am very new to SQL so sorry for all the questions

Comment: @KivanIlangakoon . . . I messed up on the `SELECT STUFF()`.  I usually put  it in a correlated subquery, so I just missed the `CROSS APPLY` -- and it makes sense like that for your purposes (because you don't want empty lists).  If this is going into an application, I would suggest that you map user into to date ranges in the app, so the query can be better optimized.